# Cómo subir un proyecto Symfony a Hostinger? [Base de datos]

Tags: sql, symfony6

Seguí los pasos de distintos tutoriales para subir mi proyecto symfony 6 a la web de hostinger pero al intentar entrar en mi dominio me devuelve un error interno - 500
Creo que se debe a la conexión de base de datos, no sé cómo conectarlo.

Principalmente no sé si funcionaría poniendo localhost y es otra cosa lo que está fallando o es eso.

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://DBUser:DBPassword@localhost:3336/DBName?charset=utf8mb4"`

Comment: Será porque estás usando localhost en otro ambiente?

Comment: En general hostinger utiliza localhost para la conexión a MySQL. Revisa el resto de datos, hay un manual en https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583552-how-to-find-your-mysql-database-details para ver tu user y tu nombre de bbdd.

Comment: Gracias Jakala, he echado un ojo y he puesto correctamente el usuario y la base de datos con su contraseña en LOCALHOST pero aún así, el problema persiste y no sé si el puerto es el correcto. He probado en el 3306 y en el 3336.